# How to extract typing information from python objects?

Tags: python, typing

Given the following declaration

```
a:str = None
```

How can programmatically enquire about the expected typing information of `a`, so that I get the value `str`, rather than `NoneType`?

Comment: The objects have no knowledge about the type annotation of the variables you've assigned them to. You would have to introspect the code to extract annotations. What, *exactly* is it that you are trying to do? Because that will likely affect which way you want to go about this.

Comment: For static type-checking in python you need [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which uses the standard library `typing`

Comment: @ninMonkey well, there are various third-party type-checkers. `mypy` has sort of become the standard, and is usually the most up-to-date with additions/changes to the type annotation standard. Indeed, that is what Guido works on currently! But there are alternatives. pytype is one, and PyCharm comes with it's own type-checker, and I've recently heard good things about pyright (Microsoft)

Comment: I am wanting to automatically generate the {getter, setter, notifier, property} boilerplate for QT from a bunch of attributes on more generic object. I could just add the type information elsewhere (which is what I did) but assigning it directly on the declaration of the variable would seem to be the neatest way of doing that. I'll checkout mypy, and some of the others. Thanks

Comment: `VS Code` has a new python static typing addon: [Pylance](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-pylance-fast-feature-rich-language-support-for-python-in-visual-studio-code/)